# Trying to make a dynamic invoice with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, invoice

I'm a very, very new JavaScript newbie, I am trying to make a dynamic invoice where I just type in the "no. of items" x "item cost" = "total". At the moment, all values are initialized to zero.

That is pretty much it. I am at the stage now where I am trying to integrate it with html, so here is a sample code (I got the html code from bootstrap based forms, I'm not trying to be creative, I'm just trying to make the form interactive).

Just ignore the subtotal and total fields below, I'll just cross that bridge when I get there. Many thanks :) Code is below:

```
[link] http://codepen.io/ascdesignstudio/pen/JKvQoq
```

Comment: Should i just pate the whole code here? I'm trying to get it to link from codepen but I'm having trouble.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Hi Prototype Chain, the link is here: http://codepen.io/ascdesignstudio/pen/JKvQoq sorry I am finding trouble putting the code here at stackoverflow directly. I'm just trying to multipy 2 fields so I can get the amount / answer. But all will appear in the html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set both the price and quantity inputs on `keyup` to run a function to calculate the product of those two input fields, you can assign that value to your third input.

```js
var totalPrice = function() {
  // get the value of the price input
  var price = document.getElementById("inputPrice").value
  //get the value of the quantity input
  var quantity = document.getElementById("inputNoOfItems").value
  // assign the product of the above two inputs to the total
  document.getElementById("inputTotal").value = price * quantity
}
```

```html
<span>Item Name</span>
<!-- on keyup of both of these inputs, run a function to determine the total -->
<input type="text" id="inputNoOfItems" value="0" onkeyup="totalPrice()">
<input type="text" id="inputPrice" value="0" onkeyup="totalPrice()">
<input type="text" id="inputTotal" value="0">
```

[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NArkyY)